# can't upgrade from mongo 3.4 to 3.6 - Server min and max wire version are incompatible

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb 3.4 cluster that I want to upgrade to 3.6. on a test run (virtualbox), I was able to do so, but with the real cluster I'm getting this `rs.status()` after calling add:

```
lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Server min and max wire version are incompatible (6,6) with client min wire version (0,5)",
            "configVersion" : -1
```

Any ideas? I've followed the instructions on mongo site, and set the compatibility to 3.4, but it doesn't work.

If anyone encounter with that, please let me know. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.

Stop the server

Delete all files from dbPath

Add the server to replica set on primary, like: rs.add("server.domain")

Start the server

Now should be ok